Union all and getting the desired results
SELECT 'load' AS type,
       id,
       sec_id,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       max_date,
       NULL AS tble_id,
       NULL AS pTime
FROM tablea
UNION ALL
SELECT 'dump',
       NULL AS id,
       NULL AS sec_int,
       NULL AS start_date,
       NULL AS end_date,
       NULL AS max_date,
       id AS tbl_id,
       Ptime
FROM [table];


I would like to get the results like this



type
id
sec_id
start_date
end_date
max_date
pTime for enter
pTime for exit




load'
1
2
2024-07-01 01:22'',
,'2024-07-01 01:35
'2024-07-01 01:44
null
null


dump
1
2
2024-07-01 01:22'',
,'2024-07-01 01:35
'2024-07-01 01:44
2024/07/01 01:50
2024/07/01 01:55



the information from load should appear on row number 2
WITH Combined AS (
    SELECT 
        'load' AS type, 
        id, 
        sec_id, 
        start_date, 
        end_date, 
        max_date, 
        NULL AS pTime 
    FROM tablea
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        'dump' AS type, 
        id, 
        sec_id AS sec_id,  -- Assuming sec_id exists in tableb or adjust as necessary
        NULL AS start_date, 
        NULL AS end_date, 
        NULL AS max_date, 
        pTime 
    FROM tableb
)


Why would you expect non-NULL data from your date columns for the row where you have 'dump' as the type? YOu are very explicitly SELECTing NULL as those values. If you want a non-NULL value, don't use a literal NULL. I don't think a UNION is what you want here, I think you want a CROSS JOIN or similar.

What would really help here is sample data and desired output for the sample data.

I don't get it. Why are you showing two different queries? In the first query you select from a table and add a fake row. In the second you select from two tables. Is one of the queries getting you the desired result? If not, in which way does the result differ from the expected one? Only in the order of the rows? How many tables are really involved? Which table contains which information? Please show sample rows of the original table(s) and the expected result for this data. Explain why you expect this result.

Your query is fine just need to add order by clause as per your requirement. Please see the below query:-
SELECT 'load' AS type, id,sec_id,start_date,end_date, max_date, NULL AS tble_id, NULL AS pTime FROM tablea
UNION ALL
SELECT 'dump', NULL AS id, NULL AS sec_int, NULL AS start_date, NULL AS end_date, NULL AS max_date, id AS tbl_id, Ptime FROM tablea order by id

Happy Coding!
